# Windows Remote Desktop -- how to not have remote screen on

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, citrix

If I work from home using windows remote desktop, my work computers would have the screen on. People at work can see my screen, what I am seeing, typing, etc.

How do I disable that? i.e. I can see my screen at home, but not show that in work/remote computer.

I am using Citrix, it downloads an ica file. I think under the hood it still uses windows remote desktop application, how do I find out whether I am actually using Windows Remote Deskop?

I use windows 8 at home and windows 7 at work.

Comment: What is your version of os (both home and work) which version of citrix are you using? The downloads ica every time sounds like a bug from a previous version. With the ICA download, most likely not using remote desktop.

Comment: This is a question for your IT department apparently. When you RDP into a Windows client PC, the screen at the console session should be locked and not viewable at the console level unless someone signs onto the PC with your same username and password or with another account at which point your session on a desktop PC would be disconnected for your remote session. Big Chris answered this part below but if there's special software to do something other than the Windows 7 default, your IT department can answer that.

Comment: The Citrix lets you access the applications so Remote Desktop from Citrix RDP icon (the ICA) is no different, just an interface into it other than a VPN connection perhaps... RDP should behave the same default way with Windows 7 regardless. When you connect via RDP to the Windows 7 machine (yes even through a Citrix interface first), the console session should still be locked and not viewable by others. Ask your IT or test this in the office one day from another machine with the Citrix URL and you will see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Windows built-in "Remote Desktop" application (`mstsc.exe`) then when you remotely connect in the remote computer will automatically "lock" so no-one can see the screen or what you're doing. They just get presented with the usual "Press Ctrl + Alt + Delete to unlock this computer".

Comment: I am using Citrix, it downloads an ica file. I think under the hood it still uses windows remote desktop application, how do I find out?

Comment: @CodeNoob  you should Update your questiom with this informations

Answer (score 1):

You can simply switch the power off (at the screen) whenever you are leaving the office.

Comment: The people at the office can simply "turn it back on again"... You should have asked if the OP is using the Windows built-in "Remote Desktop" application (`mstsc.exe`) which will lock the workstation when a user is remotely accessing it so no-one can see the remote user's actions/desktop (hint: this is the answer if using `mstsc.exe`)...

Comment: Yes, but that assumes a) malicious intent, and b) knowing when.

Comment: If you use `mstsc` then the only malicious actions are to forcibly log the user off or power the remote machine off - neither of which will allow the unauthorised access to the remote user's actions/desktop etc.